# Is it possible to detect which table is what data changed in oracle materialized view using trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

I have a materialized view and I want to detect:

- when materialized view is updated
- which table(s)'s
- what data's (or row) changed?

Comment: Sounds like a job for auditing: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php

Comment: Is auditing working with trigger. Is someone try it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MV log there should already be a trigger on the base table(s) and the triggers an populating the material view log (actually its a table)  This would assume that you are doing fast refreshes instead of complete refreshes.  Check the following tables to see if they contain the information that you are looking for:

```
select trigger_name from user_triggers
where table_name = '<you table name>'

SELECT master, log_table, rowids, primary_key
FROM user_snapshot_logs;

desc mlog$_<your table name>

desc rupd$_<your table name>
```

The mlog$_... and rupd$... name may get truncated in case the base table's name is too long.  Hope that helps you.